# Variable Scope Example Explanation

Tags: java, scope

```
public class Arcane {

    static int x;
    int y;

    public Arcane(int x) {
        int y = x + 1;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void increment() {
        y += x;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x = 5;
        {
            int x = 2;
            Arcane t = new Arcane(x);
            t.increment();
            t.print();
        }
    }
}
```

It is in my understanding that the program prints out 8 but I cannot figure out why. I tried plugging in x=5.

Comment: After this.y does the value 5 carry down for y?

Comment: I am looking for an explanation for why t ends up being 8

Comment: are you not getting error because you have not declared the variable x( where x = 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you put 5 to static variable x: `x =  5;`

Then you create yet another x valid in inner scope. Its value is 2 and you send it to constructor of Arcane that calculates `y` as `x+1` (local x), i.e. `2+1=3`.
At this point

```
static x = 5;
y = 3;
```

Now you call increment that calculates new value of `y` as `y+=x`, that is exactly as `y = y + x`,. i.e. `3+5=8`.

Then you print y that holds 8.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    x =  5; // static x is 5
    {
        int x = 2; //local x is 2
        Arcane t = new Arcane(x); //new arcane with local x = 2
        t.increment(); // add static x (5) to field y which is 3, = 8
        t.print(); //print 8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Arcane(int 2) {
     int 3 = 2 + 1;
     this.y = 3;
}

public void increment() {
    y += 5; // from static int x -> 8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this following, you're passing x=2;

Arcane t = new Arcane(2);

Then in the constructor, the value of y becomes. y=2+1=3

public Arcane(int x) {   int y = x + 1;   this.y = y; }

Back in your main method, the following method call assigns the value of y=x+y which is 5+3=8

t.increment();

Answer (score 0):

thats why.

> static int x;

is a static variable, the line:

> x =  5;

modify this static variable.

> int x = 2;

is a shadow variable, needless to say, not affecting the static one initialized early. an object is created passing the shadowed variable.
at this point y = 2 + 1 = 3.

> t.increment()

changes the value of y to 3 + 5.
at this point you got y = 8 as  the final result, its all about scoping and shadowing, basic programming concept you need to get familiarized with.