# Array does not get recognized in other jButtons

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I'm writing a program (in Netbeans) which has two buttons; One which will take the input from the user and store it in an object, and then store this object in an array. And another one which will print out all existing objects in the array on a jTextArea.

This is my class:

```
public class Car {
    public String brand;
    public String year;

  public Car (String brand, String year) {
      this.brand = brand;
      this.year = year;
  }


}
```

And this is the code I have written to go with it:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;

    Car[] carArray = new Car[b];
    carArray[a] = new Car (txtfBrand.getText(), txtfYear.getText());
    a++;
    b++;
}                                      

private void btnReadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    for (int i = 0; i < carArray.length; i++) {    //I get and error on this line for 'carArray'...
        txtaRead.setText(" " + carArray[i] + "\n");    //...And on this line, also for 'carArray'
    }
}
```

The idea for the code under the `Add`-button is to take the user input and store it in the `carArray`. When the `Read`-button then is clicked, I want everything in the `carArray` to be printed out. I thought I had accomplished this with my code, but I get an error saying:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable carArray
  location: class Car
```

I googled some on this and found out that it had something to do with the scope of variables but I couldn't find out much more than that. This maybe a very noobish question, but I would really appreciate some help:)

Comment: Define the array outside the scope of both of the methods, e.g. at class level

Comment: @Reimeus Thank you so much! This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Car[] carArray = new Car[b];`  you should declare this out side from the method as below. this links will help you to understand variable scope.

http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm

[Variable Scope Example Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400494/variable-scope-example-explanation)

[Java variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560850/java-variable-scope)

```
Car[] carArray = new Car[b];
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;


    carArray[a] = new Car (txtfBrand.getText(), txtfYear.getText());
    a++;
    b++;
}                                      

private void btnReadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    for (int i = 0; i < carArray.length; i++) {    //I get and error on this line for 'carArray'...
        txtaRead.setText(" " + carArray[i] + "\n");    //...And on this line, also for 'carArray'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I'll definitely give those links a read through!